# Sorting a dynamic object list based on another list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I have two lists. One is a dynamic list of objects. Another is a list of strings. I want to sort the object list based on the other list.

```
List<dynamic> List1; // Object1,Object2,Object3,Object4
List <String> List2; //"abc","bcd","da"
```

These objects has one of the attributes "alphabets" on whose basis it has to be sorted.

The objects may not be equal to number of elements in second list.

Comment: If one list has 3 elements (`List2`) and the other has 4 (`List1`), it will be interesting :-)

Comment: Not sure how you expect to that, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What *exactly* is expected here? How is a sort going to affect anything?

Comment: Not clear what each list is/does.  Are you saying list 1 has an attribute that is "alphabets", which you need to match against List 2 to find its sort order?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, if the indexes of the two lists align how you want them to. You'd have to ensure that the lists have the same length for this to work correctly though.

```
var result = list1
    .Select((item, index) => 
        new 
        {
            Item = item, 
            Order = list2[index]
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
    .Select(x => x.Item);
```

If they aren't the same length, what would be the criteria for the order? That would be an undefined problem. One approach would be to put them at the end of the list.

```
var result = list1.Take(list2.Length)
    .Select((item, index) => 
    new 
    {
        Item = item, 
        Order = list2[index]
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
    .Select(x => x.Item);
var concatted = result.Concat(list1.Skip(list2.Length));
```

Comment: `list2[index]` - "The objects may not be equal to number of elements in second list." as per OP's post.

Comment: This will throw an `IndexOutOfRange` once index is too big. The OP states the lists aren't equal length.

Comment: But that is exactly what the OP is asking, how to sort based on non-equal length lists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming that List1 contains a list of objects, and each object contains an attribute called "alphabet", and you want to sort this list of objects, but the sort order is specified in List2 which has the possible values of alphabet in sorted order, then you could do this:

```
int i=0;
var List2WithRowNum = from str2 in List2.AsEnumerable() select new{ rowNum = i++, str2 };
var sortedList = from obj1 in List1.AsEnumerable()
        join strKey in List2WithRowNum.AsEnumerable() on ((listObject)obj1).alphabet equals strKey.str2
        orderby strKey.rowNum
        select obj1;
```

sortedList would then be a list of your original objects (from List1) sorted by their "alphabet" attribute, in List2 order.